# How to run pom.xml from intellij directly without using cmd

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I know how to run maven pom.xml file from cmd,could anyone please explain how to do it from Intellij.Like in eclipse, we can directly right click pom.xml and click run as.Is there any such option intellij or are any additional settings need to be done for the same.Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 9):

Use: `View > Tool Windows > Maven Projects`.

You'll see something like this:

[image]

You can run any goal by ...

- Double clicking it
- Right mouse click and choose run from the context menu
- Clicking on the run icon (the green right arrow) in the menu bar

Comment: Thank you.That view was not present in 2017.2.4 version.The same is there by default in an older version of Intellij.Thank you for the help!!!!

Comment: click on "package" will run pom.xml, thanks.